# How to convert Seed to the PrivateKey?

Tags: flutter, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I'm developing a Hedera Wallet for Flutter, and I need to convert the mnemonic to the private key.

I use the [bip39](https://pub.dev/packages/bip39) to convert the mnemonic to seed.

But how can I convert the seed to the PrivateKey?

Comment: Hi Hossein did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation here https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/keys/recover-keys-from-a-mnemonic-phrase:

```js
//Use a recovered mnemonic to recover the private key
const recoveredMnemonic = await Mnemonic.fromString(mnemonic.toString());
const privateKey = await recoveredMnemonic.toPrivateKey();

//v2.0.5
```

Comment: how can we add Hedera to a Flutter project?